# husky+lint-staged runs on unstaged files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, eslint, githooks

I'm trying to add a pre-commit git hook that will run my linter only on touched (staged) files. My project is based on Create React App.

I added the following to my `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint 'src/**/*.js'",
    "lintfix": "eslint 'src/**/*.js' --fix"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*": ["npm run lintfix --", "git add"]
  }
```

The reason I run it on `"*"` is because I'm expecting the script itself (lintfix) to enforce it's configuration (`src/**/*.js`).

The problem is that I'm getting plenty of eslint errors on my entire codebase and not only on staged files as I wished.

What's the configuration I need for running my eslint **only on staged files**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From lint-staged [readme.md](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged) :

> ```
> { "*": "your-cmd" }
> ```
>
> This config will execute `your-cmd` with the list of currently staged
>   files passed as arguments.
>
> So, considering you did git add file1.ext file2.ext, lint-staged will
>   run the following command:
>
> `your-cmd file1.ext file2.ext`

So looking at your package.json, you are running the following :

```
eslint 'src/**/*.js' --fix file1.js file2.js file3.js fileX.js... ....
```

You need to replace `npm run lintfix --` by  `eslint --fix` to first test if it works (it should), then adapt your `lintfix` command without the generic `src/**/*.js` regex.

Comment: My eslint configuration runs prettier, and when run lint-staged its running on all files, not just the staged ones.